# How can I accelerate confirmations in ledger nano s?

Tags: transaction-fees, confirmations, hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet, bumpfee

I am using Ledger Nano S hardware wallet to store my bitcoins. Last week, for an experiment, I decided to send bitcoins to hitbtc currency exchange with zero btc fees. I was wondering how many hours will it take to transaction to be completed, but it turns out that transaction will never be completed with zero fee. I try to accelerate the procedure with ledger nano s option, but it failed many times as well. I am looking at my balance in blockchainfo, it looks like I have all the coins in my wallet, is not sent anywhere, but I cannot see the same balance in my ledger wallet. So does anyone know how can I access to my bitcoins? Thanks.

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few [services that can accelerate Bitcoin transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_accelerator). According to the Bitcoin wiki, [PushTx](https://pushtx.btc.com/) seems to be reliable.